# blink UILabel text swift2 ios

Tags: ios, swift2, uilabel

I see code to make text in UILabel to blink, but I am using Swift 2, and what changes does one make to have such text blink in Swift?

I just need this style only to alert the user of my app to start the game, then I don't need any other text to blink.

Comment: happy to help you,if u like it ,please accept the answer , by pressing the check mark beside the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided some code it were simpler to answer but without it it's I can do:

```
let foo =  UITextField()

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {() -> Void in
    foo.alpha = 0.0
    },
                           completion: { finished in
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                                foo.alpha = 1.0
                            })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using **animateWithDuration**.

Here i am writing in viewDidLoad(). you can use this according to your requirement.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myLabel.alpha=0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0.2, options:[.Repeat,.Autoreverse],
                      animations:{ self.myLabel.alpha=1.0}, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I figured out to do, on my own. Thanks for validating! This works in Swift 2 and with Xcode 7.3!